# Select items from another forms listview while modal window is opened

Tags: delphi, user-interface, forms, delphi-xe

I have a problem and this is little bit difficult explain, but I try.

I have a application's main window. And on this main window I have a popup dialog (another form containing listview) with customers. If I type on the main window's textbox then it pops up and automatically fills data depending on what I type. And I can select items from there by clicking mouse on item or by pressing arrow and enter keys.

Now I added new modal dialog to main window and want to access this popup dialog like I do in main window while new modal dialog is opened. If I type to new modal dialog textbox then it pops up again and fills data depending what I type.

I got working that it pops up and fills data, also I can selecting items by pressing arrow and enter keys.

Problem is that I cannot click on item like on the main form, because modal window don't let me do so.

Is there a way to click on item on this popup dialog while another modal dialog is open? Like keep both forms to be active on the same time?

Hope you understand my question.

Regards,
evilone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [EnableWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646291%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. You can call it in OnShow event handler, ex:

```
// show Form3 and call modal dialog Form2
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form3.Show;
  Form2.ShowModal;
end;

// make Form3 controls available while Form2 is modal:
procedure TForm2.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  EnableWindow(Form3.Handle, True);
end;
```

Comment: @Serg Do I have to add this code to modal dialog and pointing to popup dialog handle?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. Because I have a third from which I want to be active with Form2 opened by your example. I have Form1 - which is the main window, Form2 - which is the modal window. And I access this third window from Form1 and Form2. In Form1 all is working, but on Form2, I cannot click it, because Form2 is modal.

Comment: Still can't make it work. Maybe it's connected somehow to that I'm setting this Form1 as Form3's parent. If I put EnableWindow(Form1.Handle, True) then I can access it, otherwise not.

Comment: Thanks, after 3 hours wrestling, got it working - it was the Parent property that don't let do it.